# How to run a Google Cloud Function with a timeout of 60 min from a Google Cloud Task?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

So I have an HTTPS cloud function that has a timeout of 60 minutes.

```js
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const myFunction = onRequest(
    {
        timeoutSeconds: 3600,
        memory: "4GiB",
        maxInstances: 1,
        region: "europe-north1",
    },
    async (req, res) => {
        //code that takes up to 60 minutes
    });
```

I want to call this function from a cloud task, but apparently, the maximum timeout for a cloud task is [30 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task.FIELDS.dispatch_deadline).

```js
    import * as tasks from "@google-cloud/tasks";

    const task: tasks.protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ITask = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        },
        dispatchDeadline: , //<-- this is 30 minutes as far as I understood
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds: 50
        }
```

Is there a workaround for that?

I wouldn't mind just executing the call without waiting for the response of the cloud function (without waiting for 60 minutes).

But I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a retry configuration for your [tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#retry), and make your `Cloud Function` invocations idempotent (i.e. if a retry comes, but it's for a request that is already processing, don't process it again). Here is a blog post regarding idempotency in [`Cloud Functions`](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-retries-and-idempotency-in-action).

Comment: This even permits `--max-attempts=unlimited`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since idempotency is a new concept for me, let me check if I understood the process right.  So from what I understand this is the flow: 1) Creating a task that calls the cloud function 2) Task timeouts after 30 minutes and sets up a retry 3) Cloud function gets called again but returns early because the task is already being processed. 
If that's true, I guess misunderstood the relationship between the task and the cloud function. For some reason, thought the task would terminate the function after 30 min.

Comment: Idempotent means that **you should be able to call your Function multiple times with the same input data and the result of the initial call does not change.** for more details refer this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE) and your understanding is right but 3)As you enabled retry configuration for `Cloud task`, it will retry to call the cloud function as long as it meets retry configuration instead of terminating the task.